# Code for asynchronous data stream processing with multistage pipelines

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, producer-consumer, multiprocessing

I am trying to write some code for processing streams of asynchronous data from multiple sources (`Producer` `Nodes`), process them using a multistage pipeline of `Processors` `Nodes` and then forward them to multiple `Consumers` `Nodes`. So the way I have thought of going about it is the follows: Each `Node` has a run function which *does stuff*. A `Consumer` node has an `input` queue, `Producer` node has an `output` queue and the `Processor` node has both. I then Construct a `Pipeline` by 'connecting' `input` and `output` queues (by pointing input queue of next node to output queue of previous) of nodes and `run` all nodes *asynchronously*. Each shared queue between nodes is synchronized by a `mutex` and `condition_variable` variable which are also 'connected'. Here is the code sample for int streams:

```
    enum class PacketState{
        START,
        VALID,
        CORRUPT,
        END,
    };
    typedef struct packet{
        int data;
        PacketState state;
        explicit packet(int x):data{x},state{PacketState::VALID}{};
        packet(int d, PacketState s):data{d},state{s}{};
        packet():data{0},state{PacketState::VALID}{};
    } PacketType;
    using OutputType = PacketType;
    using InputType = OutputType;

    class Node{
    protected:
        bool stayAlive = true;
    public:
        virtual void run() = 0;
    };

    class NodesWithOutput: public Node{
    protected:
        //declare output pointers
        std::shared_ptr<Queue<OutputType>> output;
        std::shared_ptr<std::condition_variable> cvout;
        std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> m_out;
    public:
        NodesWithOutput(){
            //setup output apparatus.....
            output = std::make_shared< Queue<OutputType> >();
            cvout = std::make_shared<std::condition_variable>();
            m_out = std::make_shared<std::mutex>();
        }
        auto getOutputQueue(){return output;}
        auto getOutputCondition(){return cvout;}
        auto getOutputMutex(){return m_out;};
    };

    class NodesWithInput: public Node{
    protected:
        //declare input pointers
        std::shared_ptr<Queue<InputType>> input;
        std::shared_ptr<std::condition_variable> cvin;
        std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> m_in;
    };

    //template<typename OutputType>
    class Producer: public NodesWithOutput{
    public:
        Producer() = default;

        void run() override {
            int i = 6;
                while (stayAlive) {
                    //generate stream of ints..
                    OutputType dataPacket{--i};
                    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
                    // push to output queue
                    {
                        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(*m_out);
                        output->push(dataPacket);
                        cvout->notify_all();
                    }
                    if(i <= 0) stayAlive = false;
                }

            OutputType dataPacket{-1,PacketState::END};
            // push to output queue
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(*m_out);
                output->push(dataPacket);
            }
            // This is the right place to notify right?..
            // **not** inside the guarded block
            cvout->notify_all();
        }
    };

    //template<typename InputType, typename OutputType>
    // HOW DO I DO THIS PROPERLY?
    class Processor:public NodesWithOutput, public NodesWithInput {
    private:
        int scale;
    protected:
        //HOW DO I FIX THIS?
        //?? this doesn't seem right!
        bool stayAlive = NodesWithOutput::stayAlive;
    public:
        Processor():scale{1}{}

        void setScale(int s){ scale = s;}

        void setInput(Producer& other){
            input = other.getOutputQueue();
            m_in = other.getOutputMutex();
            cvin = other.getOutputCondition();
        }

        void run() override {
            while(stayAlive) {
                //wait for input
                {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ulock(*m_in);
                    //Should I wait for notify from cvout of previous node?
                    //I mean this cvin will finally point to previous cvout!
                    cvin->wait(ulock, [this](){return !input->empty();});
                }
                //process input
                {
                    std::unique_ptr<PacketType> ip;
                    //read from input queue
                    {
                        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(*m_in);
                        ip = input->pop();
                    }
                    //process and
                    OutputType o;
                    o.state = ip->state;
                    if(ip->state != PacketState::END) {
                        o.data = (*ip).data * scale;
                        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(50));
                    }else{
                        stayAlive = false;
                    }

                    //write to output queue
                    {
                        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(*m_out);
                        output->push(o);
                    }
                    cvout->notify_all();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    //template<typename InputType>
    class Consumer: public NodesWithInput {
    public:
        Consumer() = default;
        void setInput(Processor& other){
            input = other.getOutputQueue();
            m_in = other.getOutputMutex();
            cvin = other.getOutputCondition();
        }
        void run() override {
            while(stayAlive) {
                //wait for data
                {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> ulock(*m_in);
                    cvin->wait(ulock, [this](){ return !input->empty();});
                }
                //Consume data data
                std::unique_ptr<InputType> ip;
                {
                    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(*m_in);
                    ip = input->pop();
                }
                if(ip->state == PacketState::END) break;

                //process data
                std::cout << "Consumed: " << ip->data << std::endl;
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5));
            }
        }
    };

    class Pipeline {
    private:
        std::vector< Node* > nodes;
    public:
        Pipeline(){
            nodes = std::vector< Node* >();
        }

        ~Pipeline() = default;

        void buildAndRun() {
            // Node 1
            Producer randInt;
            //nodes.push_back(&randInt);

            Processor multiplier;
            //HOW DO IF FIX THIS?
            //'Node' is an ambiguous base of 'Processor'
            //nodes.push_back(&multiplier);
            multiplier.setInput(randInt);
            multiplier.setScale(2);


            Consumer printer;
            //nodes.push_back(&printer);
            printer.setInput(multiplier);

            //FIX move to separate function which operates on nodes vector....
            auto run = [&](){
                // Put these in a loop if nodes vector works out...
                auto t1 = std::async(std::launch::async, &Producer::run, randInt);
                auto t2 = std::async(std::launch::async, &Processor::run, multiplier);
                auto t3 = std::async(std::launch::async, &Consumer::run, printer);

                t1.get();
                t2.get();
                t3.get();
            };
            run();

        }


    };
```

Not this is the first time I am writing `async` code and I have a questions! Some are in code comments but here are some major ones:

1. Is the general architecture of the code OK or should I change it? Do you see any obvious (or non-obvious) issues I may will run into using this pattern?
2. The `Queue` I am using is a thread safe queue Is that an overkill? Should I just use simple std::queue for holding data packets?
3. This may be more of a `stackoverflow` question, but how do I properly inherit from two different classes (`NodesWithInput` and `Nodeswithoutput`) so that I can have a `vector` of `Node`s in `Pipeline`? (I shout 'how to fix...' in code comments for stuff that I haven't figure out yet.)

Here is the code for the `Queue` class along with test `main` function for runnable sample.

```
    class Queue {
    private:
        std::queue< std::unique_ptr<T> > _queue;
        std::mutex _mutex;
        //?? change this to a shared ptr 
        // add a shared ptr to condition and point 
        // node sync variables to connecting queue sync variables..
    public:
        Queue() = default;
        Queue(const Queue<T> &) = delete;
        Queue& operator=(const Queue<T>& ) =delete;

        Queue(Queue<T> && other) noexcept {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
            _queue = std::move(other._queue);
        }

        virtual ~Queue(){}

        size_t size() const {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
            return _queue.size();
        }

        bool empty() const {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
            return _queue.empty();
        }


        std::unique_ptr<T> pop() {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
            //check empty only when locked
            if(_queue.empty()){
                return nullptr;
            }
            auto front = std::move(_queue.front());
            _queue.pop();
            return front;
        }

        void push(const T& packet){
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_mutex);
            _queue.push(std::make_unique<T>(packet));
        }
    };


    int main() {
        std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
        Pipeline p;
        p.buildAndRun();
        std::cout << "Goodbye, World!" << std::endl;

        return 0;
    }
```

4. Is there a way to simplify the Code for `Nodes` by somehow adding `condition_variable` to the `Queue` and using that to synchronize and signal all output nodes to stop wait? (I have some ideas for this in the comments of the `Queue` class.. but need to be sure about race conditions and blocking stuff...)
5. Finally, a bit more open ended for the future.. I have to make the ``Queue` bounded at some point. What would be the most optimal way to handle this? The processing times of different nodes could be different and large queues could form at 'some' places but not others. Is it possible to have a global bound on total number of queued items rather than local bound on each queue?

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## General

1. `typedef` is not needed in C++ for `struct`s
2. In C++, one tends to have `public` members first and then private members. similarly constructors and functions generally come before member variables.
3. All classes with `virtual` functions must have a `virtual` destructor.
4. It's considered bad practice to have `protected` members. It is also considered bad practice to have member variables in base classes that are pure `virtual`
5. Avoid having `_` as a prefix to before any names. Its against C++ guidelines.

## Architecture

1. Your hierarchies are too deep. There is very little to be gained from having a `Node` class. Also, it is the cause of the ambigous base error in `Processor`. Look up diamond dependency issue.
2. The `NodesWithOutput` and `NodesWithInput` is leaking variables. Everytime, the getters are called a new `shared_ptr` is created. Looking at the usage you could have easily made it into a `struct`.
3. Further there is no point having `NodesWithOutput` and `NodesWithInput`, why not just create a `class` called `Pipe` and let the `Nodes` have a `shared_ptr` to it?
4. Do you intend to write a new `Producer`, `Consumer` and `Processor` class everytime you have to have a new way to produce, process or consume something? This is too much broilerplate code to achieve something mundane.
5. Since the `Queue`s are shared it which means that if you have multiple consumers then only one of the queue will get the packet.

## Final word

There are many other issue. But the main issue is the architecture. It is needlessly complicated. I would start with something like this.
Disclaimer: The code below is not not tested. It only serves as a rough sketch of how I would rearchitect the code

```
#include <memory>
#include <queue>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
class Queue
{
public:
    T pop()
    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock(mMutex);
        mConditionVariable.wait(lock, [this]{return !mQueue.empty();});    
        auto element = mQueue.front(); 
        mQueue.pop();
        return element;
    }

    void push(T&& t)
    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock(mMutex);
        mQueue.push(t);
    }

    bool empty()
    {
        auto lock = std::unique_lock(mMutex);
        return true;
    }

private:
    std::condition_variable mConditionVariable;
    std::queue<T> mQueue;
    std::mutex mMutex;
};

template<typename T>
class Producer
{
public:

    void run()
    {
        while(1)
        {
            mOutputQueue->push(mProduce());
        }
    }

    void connect(std::shared_ptr<Queue<T>> q)
    {
        mOutputQueue = q;
    }

private:    
    std::function<T()> mProduce;
    std::shared_ptr<Queue<T>> mOutputQueue;
};

template<typename T>
class Processor
{
public:

    void run()
    {
        while(1)
        {
            mOutputQueue->push(
                mProcess(
                    mInputQueue.pop()
                )
            );
        }
    }

    void connectInput(std::shared_ptr<Queue<T>> q)
    {
        mInputQueue = q;
    }

    void connectOutput(std::shared_ptr<Queue<T>> q)
    {
        mOutputQueue = q;
    }

private:
    std::function<void(T)> mProcess;
    std::shared_ptr<Queue<T>> mInputQueue;
    std::shared_ptr<Queue<T>> mOutputQueue;
};

template<typename T>
class Consumer
{
public:

    void run()
    {
        while(1)
        {
            auto value = mInputQueue->pop();
            mConsume(std::move(value));
        }
    }

    void connectInput(std::shared_ptr<Queue<T>> q)
    {
        mInputQueue = q;
    }


private:
    std::function<void(T&)> mConsume;
    std::shared_ptr<Queue<T>> mInputQueue;
};
```

If you can refactor the code to look something like this and repost it. I can review it and make it robust. I suspect there are race conditions which we are unaware of but they will start to be apparent only after the code is readable.

Comment: You correctly point out several mistakes, like “All classes with virtual functions must have a virtual destructor.” However, it's quite possible the poster doesn't know why you should do that. It helps if you could add links to other StackExchange questions (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/461203/5481471)) or other online resources (like [this one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Virtual_destructors)) that add some context.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Yes. I forgot to give rationle for a lot of my suggestions

Answer (score 2):

## Architecture

I agree with Ajinkya Kamat that the architecture of your code is too complex and can be simplified. I would even go further than Ajinkya suggested, and consider not making `class`es for the producers, consumers and processors at all. Instead, those can be made stand-alone functions. You pass in any objects needed as arguments. So for example, a really simplified version of the consumer could look like:

```
template<typename T>
void run_consumer(std::shared_ptr<Queue<T>> q, std::function<void(T&)> consume)
{
    while (true)
    {
        consume(q->pop());
    }
}
```

## You don't need `std::shared_ptr`s

While you can use `std::shared_ptr<Queue<T>>` to share queues between nodes, you don't actually need all the features `std::shared_ptr` provides. If you can create the `Queue` objects before creating the producers/processors/consumers, then you can just pass references to the queues to the latter. So for example:

```
Queue<int> randint_queue;
Queue<int> multiplied_queue;

{
    auto t1 = std::async(std::launch::async,
                         run_producer<int>, randint,
                         randint_queue);

    auto t2 = std::async(std::launch::async,
                         run_processor<int, int>, multiplier,
                         randint_queue, multiplied_queue);

    auto t3 = std::async(std::launch::async,
                         run_consumer<int>, printer,
                         multiplied_queue);
}
```

Where now something like `run_consumer()` looks like:

```
template<typename T>
void run_consumer(Queue<T>& queue, std::function<void(T&)> consume)
{
    while (true)
    {
        consume(queue.pop());
    }
}
```

And the actual functions that do something can look like:

```
void printer(const int& value) {
    std::cout << "Consumed: " << value << '\n';
}
```

Or even be passed in as lambdas.

## Make building a pipeline easier

Your code and even my suggestions so far don't really make building the pipeline itself much easier. There is still the need to manually create nodes (in whatever form), and to connect those nodes together. Wouldn't it be much nicer if you could make a whole pipeline in one statement?

```
// With a variadic function:
auto pipeline = make_pipeline(randint, multiplier, printer);

// Or perhaps even using operator overloading:
auto pipeline = randint | multiplier | printer;
```

You can actually make something like the above. The result of `make_pipeline()` would be of a type that holds the `Queue`s and `std::future`s returned by the `std::async` calls.

I am leaving this as an excercise for the reader, but the main point I want to make with this is that you should try to find ways to make building and using pipelines as easy as possible, and avoid the caller from having to create complicated `class`es.

## Issues with `Queue`

There are some issues with your implementation of a thread-safe queue:

### The move-constructor is unsafe

In the move-constructor, you lock the mutex of `this`, but that does not do anything useful. It would be much better to lock `other._mutex`, to prevent other threads from manipulating the queue while you are moving it. But that raises even more questions: what happens after `other._queue` has been moved from and the mutex is unlocked again? It's undefined what the other threads will see.

You could say that no other thread should use or even hold a reference to a `Queue` that is being moved from, but the compiler won't enforce that. It's much better to avoid this altogether and to delete the move-constructor.

### Remove `size()` and `empty()`

This is a common mistake. While you do lock the mutex inside the `size()` and `empty()` member functions, consider that by the time the value is returned, the mutex is no longer locked, so the actual size can already have been changed before the caller looks at the return value. This means the caller cannot trust that value, and should not rely on it. I strongly recommend you remove these functions to avoid that issue.

That brings me to the following:

### Let the `Queue` do the waiting

Instead of having callers check `empty()` and waiting until something is pushed before calling `pop()`, move the logic for waiting for the queue to be non-empty into `Queue` itself.

### Add a way to signal that work is finished

Typically, a queue will have a producer and a consumer. At some point, the producer is finished. You then want the queue to be drained by the consumer, and the consumer to know when all the work has been done so it can quit itself. To do this, you need some way to tell the queue that it is done, and after the final item has been popped, it should be able to notify the consumer about this somehow.

One way would be to have a way to set a flag, and let `pop()` return a [`std::optional<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional) which contains a `T` when there was still something in the queue, and [`std::nullopt`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt) if the queue is empty and the flag is set. This way, the consumer loop can simply look like:

```
void run_consumer(Queue<T>& queue, std::function<void(T&)> consume)
{
    while (auto item = queue.pop())
    {
        consume(*item);
    }
}
```

## Think about error handling

What if something goes wrong somewhere in the pipeline? It could be at the beginning, in the middle or at the end. If the consumer dies, should the producer keep producing? The queues would grow and eventually run out of memory. You should have some way to detect errors, and have some way to propagate them so the whole pipeline will terminate.